# SharePoint 2010, How change a style of webpart?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I am new in SP, I have a listView in a webpart and I need to enlarge it to be the 100% width.
I need a simple way to do this.

people keep talking about SP css, and preventing affecting on all WebParts in the system

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to load it into a Web Part Zone that occupies the full width of the page. Then you can use the Appearance tab in the browser UI to further tweak how the Web Part looks. You may or may not need to use CSS to tweak the padding around it.

If the ListView itself is not occupying 100% of the Web Part, try adding a fixed width to it, which may save you the trouble of having to tweak any CSS for the Web Part itself.

If you need to apply custom CSS, you have two options:

(1) Add an alternate style sheet via the browser UI (master page admin). Ideally you would deploy your branding as part of a Feature, which gives you the benefit of source controlling your branding artifacts:

[Developing SharePoint 2010 features using Visual Studio 2010](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2011/10/27/developing-sharepoint-2010-features-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

[Creating Features](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/servermstpageforsitecollect_feature/)

(2) Use SharePoint Designer to apply custom CSS.

Comment: Is there a way to do it inline via Visual Studio as we do in asp.net.  I mean for WebPartZone.

I have a module to deploy a publishing page.

Comment: Have you created the ListView in VS, and if so, can you show us the code or markup? Is it a SharePoint ListView Web Part?